# I need to call a particular number in the contacts

Tags: android, listview, contacts

**I have to create an android app which displays the contact list in the phone. I am successfully managed to create it, but how to call a particular number on click (which we select)?**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView lView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    ContentResolver resolver=getContentResolver();

    Cursor c=resolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);

    String[] from=new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER};

    int[] to=new int[]{R.id.textView1,R.id.textView2};
    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.indi_view, c, from, to);

    lView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just want to initiate the intent with ACTION_CALL like this.

First of all grab the phone number from the item from which the click happens.And use the code to initiate a call.

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:"+phonenumber));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: Yes totaly agree with this "Intent.ACTION_CALL" is mainly used for calling purpose in android.!